# Symmetric DS Sync issues

Tags: postgresql, symmetricds

Facing below error in one of the node.

```
2017-12-22 09:26:40,766 ERROR [SymmetricDS] [qtp16020374-21] Received an error from node nodeB for batch 12836196.  Check the outgoing_batch table for more info.
2017-12-22 09:27:10,490 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-2] Routed 4 data events in 525 ms
2017-12-22 09:27:41,003 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-15] Routed 4 data events in 456 ms
2017-12-22 09:28:11,554 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-13] Routed 4 data events in 497 ms
2017-12-22 09:28:42,128 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-20] Routed 4 data events in 510 ms
2017-12-22 09:29:12,775 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-3] Routed 4 data events in 598 ms
2017-12-22 09:29:43,395 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-4] Routed 4 data events in 571 ms
2017-12-22 09:30:04,145 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-15] Routed 4 data events in 703 ms
2017-12-22 09:30:36,196 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-18] Routed 4 data events in 962 ms
2017-12-22 09:30:38,478 ERROR [SymmetricDS] [qtp16020374-23] Received an error from node nodeB for batch **12836196**.  Check the outgoing_batch table for more info.
2017-12-22 09:31:07,149 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-19] Routed 4 data events in 784 ms
2017-12-22 09:31:38,217 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-18] Routed 4 data events in 829 ms
```

I tried to do this:

```
update sym_outgoing_batch set status='OK' where batch_id='XXXXXX'
```

But it didn't work out.

What could be the permanent solution to this?

SymmetricDS version is 2.5.8

Comment: I dont know what is `SymmetricDS` but the query seem to be ok. What you saw in `outgoing_batch`  ?? If that query isnt the one running the batch you should show us the additional code

Answer (score 0):

SSH or remote connect to the node that is throwing the exception found in `sym_outgoing_batch.node_id` and check the logs looking for a stack trace. It will tell you more about the issue.

Comment: I did check the batch id mentioned above. It says ERROR: dup
licate key value violates unique constraint "user_xxx_key"+

Comment: Lookup the table and the values that are trying to be inserted. What's the statement? Update or insert?

Comment: It's an insert statement.

Comment: Than you'll have to find the table, declare a conflict detection with fallback detection resolution which will transform the insert statement into an update statement if the row exists at the target node

Comment: I know the table name. How can I do the same? Just changing I to U?

Comment: As I said insert into sym_conflict an entry for this table with resolution fallback

Comment: What should be resolution fallback? Can u share an example.

Comment: Is it resolve row only or resolve changes only? Also it doesn't show table name/ or symmetric.properties?

Comment: Also i dont see sym_conflict table. All i see are below tables/sequences.
sym_data_event,sym_data_gap,sym_data_ref
sym_incoming_batch,sym_lock,sym_node,sym_node_channel_ctl,sym_node_group
sym_node_group_channel_window,sym_node_group_link,sym_node_host,sym_node_host_channel_stats,sym_node_host_job_stats
sym_node_host_stats,sym_node_identity,sym_node_security,sym_outgoing_batch,sym_parameter,sym_registration_redirect,sym_registration_request,sym_router,sym_transform_column
sym_transform_table,sym_trigger,sym_trigger_router

Comment: Something is wrong there. Are you querying the central DB where the symmetricDs configuration is stored? `sym_trigger`, `sym_router`, etc...

Comment: Yes i'm queriying the server where symmetric ds is installed & running. Only thing is its old symmetric ds 2.x

Comment: I don't have enough experience with that version. Is it possible to upgrade to a later version?

Comment: Its on production and older version. I have upgraded on my product.